# Mongodb bulkwrite updateOne based on date in last element of array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to update using `Mongoose` and `MongoDB` bulkwrite based on the date of the last element which is in an array.

**Original document**:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "507f1f11bcf86cd799439011"
    },
    "company": "ABC",
    "historical": [{
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5e0af1c63b6122125c1b42cb"
            },
            "month": {
                "$date": "2015-12-01T05:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "data": [{
                    "date": {
                        "$date": "2015-12-14T05:00:00.000Z"
                    },
                    "open": 11.6224,
                    "high": 11.6224,
                    "low": 10.5124,
                    "close": 10.5124,
                    "adjClose": 10.5124,
                    "volume": 19100,
                    "change": -1.11,
                    "changePercent": -9.551,
                    "vwap": 10.8824,
                    "changeOverTime": -0.09551
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "dividend": [ {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "payout": 0.11
        }, {
            "date": {
                "$date": "2020-07-24T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "payout": 0.11
        }
    ]
}
```

I have an data array - arr (reduced elements for clarity):

```
[{
        "data": {
            "date": "2020-10-23",
            "payout": 0.12
        },
        "company": "ABC"
    }, {
        "data": {
            "date": "2020-10-23",
            "payout": 0.12,
        },
        "company": "DEF"
    }
]
```

I am trying to run bulkwrite and update the document matched by pushing into the "dividend" array if the last index in "dividend" date is earlier than the date in the data array.
**Attempted query**:

```
var ops = arr.map(function (info) {
        return {
          updateOne: {
            filter: {
              company: info.company,
              'dividend.1.date': { // how can I retrieve latest date without explicitly specifying the index?
                $lt: new Date(info.data.date)
              }
            },
            update: { $push: { dividend: info.data } }
          }
        };
      });

      collection.bulkWrite(ops, function (err, r) {
        // carry on with result
      });
```

**Desired result document**:

```
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "507f1f11bcf86cd799439011"
        },
        "company": "ABC",
        "historical": [{
                "_id": {
                    "$oid": "5e0af1c63b6122125c1b42cb"
                },
                "month": {
                    "$date": "2015-12-01T05:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "data": [{
                        "date": {
                            "$date": "2015-12-14T05:00:00.000Z"
                        },
                        "open": 11.6224,
                        "high": 11.6224,
                        "low": 10.5124,
                        "close": 10.5124,
                        "adjClose": 10.5124,
                        "volume": 19100,
                        "change": -1.11,
                        "changePercent": -9.551,
                        "vwap": 10.8824,
                        "changeOverTime": -0.09551
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "dividend": [ {
                "date": {
                    "$date": "2020-04-24T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "payout": 0.11
            }, {
                "date": {
                    "$date": "2020-07-24T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                "payout": 0.11
            },
                {
                    "date": {
                        "$date": "2020-10-23T00:00:00.000Z"
                    },
                    "payout": 0.12
                }
        ]
    }
```

As the data array might get pretty large, I would prefer to do it in a single round trip to the database instead of using multiple updates. Is this something that can be done with `Mongoose` and `MongoDB`? Hope someone can help me out on this query. Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: `if the last index in "dividend" date is earlier than the date in the data array` - hmm, do you need to get the last date of current bulkwrite and will the last element always have the latest date? You could try using 1 separate query (with `$max` operator) to get latest date and then simply check if your element in map() has greater date or not

Comment: @GytisTG Hi, I will try to answer from what I understand. As the api data might not be always consistent, I hope to have that extra check that both the company matches and date in the "dividend" is earlier than that in arr (Not to push to "dividend" if the data for same date is already in document). Yes, the "dividend" array is arranged such that the last element will have the latest date. By separate query, you meant to query outside of `bulkwrite` or within the `bulkwrite`? Do you mind showing how can I retrieve the latest date and check on the date this way ?